# Order of drawing in DirectX 11

Tags: graph, 2d, directx-11, orthographic

I'm writing a small 2d engine in DirectX 11 with a Orthogonal projection and dynamic index and vertex buffers. The depth buffer is disable. To draw image i'm using quad build from two triangles and put texture on it. Every things works great but there is a problem with order of drawing. When i'm drawing images in same place, apparently the one drawn as first. Everything is showing inversely! Functions ClearDepthStencilView, ClearRenderTargetView and Present run once at the end in real time loop.I apologise for my English. Please help.

Creating depth buffer

```
D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC depthBufferDesc;
ZeroMemory(&depthBufferDesc, sizeof(depthBufferDesc));

// Set up the description of the depth buffer.
// Set up the description of the depth buffer.

depthBufferDesc.Width = Width;
depthBufferDesc.Height = Height;
depthBufferDesc.MipLevels = 1;
depthBufferDesc.ArraySize = 1;
depthBufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_D32_FLOAT_S8X24_UINT;
depthBufferDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
depthBufferDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
depthBufferDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
depthBufferDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_DEPTH_STENCIL;
depthBufferDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
depthBufferDesc.MiscFlags = 0;


// Create the texture for the depth buffer using the filled out description.
 d3d11Device->CreateTexture2D(&depthBufferDesc, NULL, &depthStencilBuffer);


//Describe our Depth/Stencil Buffer
D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_DESC depthStencilDesc;

depthStencilDesc.DepthEnable = false;
depthStencilDesc.DepthWriteMask = D3D11_DEPTH_WRITE_MASK_ALL;
depthStencilDesc.DepthFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_LESS;
depthStencilDesc.StencilEnable = true;
depthStencilDesc.StencilReadMask = 0xFF;
depthStencilDesc.StencilWriteMask = 0xFF;
depthStencilDesc.FrontFace.StencilFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
depthStencilDesc.FrontFace.StencilDepthFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_INCR;
depthStencilDesc.FrontFace.StencilPassOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
depthStencilDesc.FrontFace.StencilFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_ALWAYS;
depthStencilDesc.BackFace.StencilFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
depthStencilDesc.BackFace.StencilDepthFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_DECR;
depthStencilDesc.BackFace.StencilPassOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
depthStencilDesc.BackFace.StencilFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_ALWAYS;

hr = d3d11Device->CreateDepthStencilState(&depthStencilDesc, &depthStencilState);
CheckError(hr,"CreateDepthStencilState");

hr = d3d11Device->CreateDepthStencilView(depthStencilBuffer, NULL, &depthStencilView);
CheckError(hr,"CreateDepthStencilView"); 

//Create our Render Target
hr = d3d11Device->CreateRenderTargetView( BackBuffer, NULL, &renderTargetView );
CheckError(hr,"CreateRenderTargetView");

//Set our Render Target
d3d11DevCon->OMSetRenderTargets( 1, &renderTargetView, depthStencilView );
```

Drawing image(Update inuse texture, vertex and shaders buffer)

```
if(inuseTexture!=0 && inuseTexture!=image->Texture)
{
Flush();
}

Vertex quad[4];

quad[0]=Vertex( posx, posy-image->texHeight,                    0.1f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
quad[1]=Vertex( posx, posy,                                     0.1f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
quad[2]=Vertex( posx + image->texWidth,posy,                    0.1f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
quad[3]=Vertex( posx + image->texWidth, posy-image->texHeight,  0.1f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE resource;
ZeroMemory(&resource,sizeof(resource));

hr = pd3d11DevCon->Map(VertBuffer, 0, MapType, 0, &resource);
CheckError(hr,"Map-VertBuffer");

char* bufferData = static_cast<char*>(resource.pData);
memcpy(bufferData+QuadCount*sizeof(quad), &quad, sizeof(quad));
pd3d11DevCon->Unmap(VertBuffer, 0);

DWORD QuadIndices[6];

QuadIndices[0] = 0+4*QuadCount;
QuadIndices[1] = 1+4*QuadCount;
QuadIndices[2] = 2+4*QuadCount;
QuadIndices[3] = 0+4*QuadCount;
QuadIndices[4] = 2+4*QuadCount;
QuadIndices[5] = 3+4*QuadCount;

ZeroMemory(&resource,sizeof(resource));

hr = pd3d11DevCon->Map(IndexBuffer, 0, MapType, 0, &resource);
CheckError(hr,"Map-IndexBuffer");

bufferData = static_cast<char*>(resource.pData);
memcpy(bufferData+QuadCount*sizeof(DWORD)*6,&QuadIndices,sizeof(DWORD)*6);
pd3d11DevCon->Unmap(IndexBuffer,0);

inuseTexture = image->Texture;
QuadCount++;
MapType=D3D11_MAP_WRITE_NO_OVERWRITE;
```

Drawing all stuff

```
//Set the default blend state (no blending) for opaque objects
pd3d11DevCon->OMSetBlendState(0, 0, 0xffffffff);

//Render opaque objects//

pd3d11DevCon->RSSetState(WireFrame);
//Create the Input Layout

pd3d11DevCon->UpdateSubresource( cbPerObjectBuffer, 0, NULL, &cbPerObj, 0, 0 ); 

pd3d11DevCon->VSSetConstantBuffers( 0, 1, &cbPerObjectBuffer );

pd3d11DevCon->PSSetShaderResources( 0, 1, &inuseTexture );
pd3d11DevCon->PSSetSamplers( 0, 1, &CubesTexSamplerState );

pd3d11DevCon->DrawIndexed( 6*QuadCount, 0,0);
//Present the backbuffer to the screen

MapType=D3D11_MAP_WRITE_DISCARD;
QuadCount=0;
inuseTexture=0;
```

Comment: I see you have created a depth/stencil state but I can't see the call to `OMSetDepthStencilState` - is this missing?

Comment: Yes, OMSetDepthStencilState was missing. Adding this function solved the problem. Thank you.